# what happens when a session variable is assigned to a viewstate?

Tags: html, asp.net, session, viewstate

If I have a session["test"] = some "hashtable" object, and I assign this session variable to a view state object Viewstate["test"], what happens when the session variable expires, or changes?

Does the view state variable store only a reference to it, or its own copy?

If session["test"] gets reassigned or set to null, does the view state variable also get reassigned/set to null?

Answer (score 1):

They are separate since ViewState is backed by a hidden field in the markup. Session is stored in memory with an explicit expiration time. ViewState is not subject to this since it is serialized/deserialized from a hidden field for every request/response.

Just view source on your page and you will find a hidden field called `ViewState` It's base 64 encoded, but if you decode it you will see the content in clear text.